# Problema para un dato que no puedo pintar

Tags: java, itext

A continuación coloco un fragmento del código:

```
        for (int indiceDocto = 0; indiceDocto < conceptos.getLength(); indiceDocto++) {

            Node concepto = conceptos.item(indiceDocto);
            Node adden = adendas.item(indiceDocto);

            desc.addCell(defineTextoGral(introduceEtiquetaSiExiste(concepto, "Clave", "", false), 1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK, 7, Font.NORMAL, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, 0, 0, 1, 0));
            desc.addCell(defineTextoGral(introduceEtiquetaSiExiste(concepto, "Concepto", "", false), 1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK, 7, Font.NORMAL, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, 0, 0, 1, 0));
            System.out.println("concepto = " + concepto);
            NodeList Anlist = concepto.getChildNodes();
            String dias = null;
            String horasExtras = null;
            String tipoHoras = null;
            String importeHoras = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < Anlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nodo = Anlist.item(i);
                if ((nodo.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) && nodo.getNodeName().equals("nomina12:HorasExtra")) {
                    org.w3c.dom.Element e = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nodo;
                    dias = e.getAttribute("Dias");
                    horasExtras = e.getAttribute("HorasExtra");
                    tipoHoras = e.getAttribute("ImportePagado");
                    importeHoras = e.getAttribute("TipoHoras");


                } else {
                    System.out.println("No hay dato de horas ");
                }
            }

            String DiasDevengados = introduceEtiquetaSiExiste(adden, "DiasDevengados", "", false);
            String DiasPorDevengar = introduceEtiquetaSiExiste(adden, "DiasPorDevengar", "", false);
            String clave = DiasDevengados+" "+DiasPorDevengar;

            if (horasExtras == null || horasExtras.equals("")) {
                desc.addCell(defineTextoGral(clave, 1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK, 7, Font.NORMAL, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, 0, 1, 0));
            } else {
                desc.addCell(defineTextoGral(horasExtras, 1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK, 7, Font.NORMAL, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, 0, 1, 0));
            }
}
```

Pasa que quiero colocar dos datos que son DiasDevengados y DiasPorDevengar estos datos vienen de un xml, se esta construyendo un pdf con itext de java, pero entonces en este ciclo no se como colocar los datos para que hagan iteración como los demás datos este es el nodo de xml: <sap:SAPAddenda xmlns:sap="http://www.sar.com.mx/cfdi/addenda" PayGroup="MEX-MONTHLY" cancelacion="0" e-mail="rrr@hotmail.com" status="0" DiasDevengados="8" DiasPorDevengar="4"/>